# What's the correct way to get the a default index.html file in this simple Clojure Ring app to have the right Content-Type?

Tags: clojure, middleware, ring, compojure

### Synopsis

Please note, this question isn't about how to serve a static file — *that's working* — it's about the special case when `wrap-file` delivers an index file by default and, for lack of a file extension in the URL, the wrong mime-type is being assigned to the Content-Type header.

**How does one get the correct mime type on index files served by default?**

*Current answers don't address how to do this yet, and the workaround
I've come up with doesn't scale.*

---

### Working Code

Here's a simplified fragment from a [Clojure](https://clojure.org/) application using [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) and [Ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring) [middleware](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts#middleware):

```
(def app
   (-> handler
      (wrap-file "public")   ; If the route is a static file in public, serve it instead
      (wrap-content-type)))  ; Deduce and add the proper Content-Type header
```

The intent is to serve up any [routes](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail), but if there's a local file in the `public` directory serve it instead, finally add a meaningful `Content-Type` header with the corresponding [mime type](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/util/mime_type.clj).  **All this works perfectly.**

---

### The Problem

When I browse to the base URL, it *does* serve `index.html` as expected, but it does *not* get a Content-Type of `text/html`, but rather `application/octet-stream`.

- [ring.middleware.file/wrap-file](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.file.html#var-wrap-file) indicates that the `index-files?` option defaults to true, and this explains why a URL with no paths correctly serves the file. This appears to be the pedantic way of [serving static resources](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Static-Resources).
- [ring.middleware.content-type/wrap-content-type](http://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.content-type.html) indicates that the mime-type is deduced by the *file extension* in the URI, and without one defaults to `application/octet-stream`. As the URL contain *no filename*, this function is 'properly' doing what it states.

**This begs the question, how to assign Content-Type by contents of the response's body?**

However, it's ill-advised to have [middleware reads the `:body` common problems](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Common-Problems), because it's a mutable InputStream that can only be read *once*. So that's obviously not the right way.

**Is there a better way to serve the index.html by default?**

### An Ugly Workaround

The current ugly workaround is to have a special-case route that sets the Content-Type manually. *<cringe/>*

Worse, this solution doesn't scale, should an index file be served from
a subdirectory.

Consequently, I'm looking for a Middleware solution, not a routing hack.

### Experiments

**Exploring the Execution Order of the Middleware and Its Consequences:**

Admittedly, although I understand the thread macro ([->](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros)) in that `(-> x A B)` transforms into `(B (A x) )`, I still get a little jumbled in my head when working out the *order* that the execution flow resolved through a *middle-ware chain* to an eventual handler with routes. The reason for this stumbling is that code can mess with the request before calling the the handler it was passed, as well as fiddle with the response before returning. The order things need to be in doesn't feel "obvious" to know when I'm augmenting the request with details going in or twiddling with the response coming out, or the more complicated case of doing a different behavior based on some condition.

e.g., Does `wrap-file` happen "before" or "after" the handler has constructed a response, as the order matters in the threading? I feel this should be more intuitive to me, without having to run to the [source code](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/95e4ca25d5b98c45f927b32b5c3c85c21c999d96/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/file.clj#L59) as much as I'm doing.

As it appears possible to have [middleware applied only when a specific route matches](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Middleware), it may be that I'm making more of a distinction between Middleware and Handlers than perhaps I should.

Swapping the order (to test the threading-order assumptions) does not do what you think:

```
(def app                     ; THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF BROKEN CODE - DON'T USE IT
   (-> handler
      (wrap-content-type)))  ; WRONG ORDER - DON'T DO THIS   (EXAMPLE ONLY)
      (wrap-file "public")   ; WRONG ORDER - DON'T DO THIS   (EXAMPLE ONLY)
```

It "works," but for the *wrong reason*.  The `index.html` file will get delivered and renders "properly," but only because there *is no Content-Type* added. The browser, for lack of a specified mime type, makes an educated guess and happens to guess correctly.

Since the goal *is* to have a Content-Type in the header, this suggests the threaded order was correct to start with.

### What Middleware Should Be Used To Deliver Index Pages?

So with information in hand of what not to do, **what is it I *should* be doing to deliver the default status index.html file when the URL doesn't specify it by name, since there's no extension to examine?**

- WORKS  — http://localhost/index.html (serves page with correct mime type)
- BROKEN — http://localhost/ (serves same page, but with the wrong content type, so the browser tries to download it)

Is there a better middleware stack, or even a recommended one, that someone could walk me through?

---

UPDATE 2020-05-24: Submitted [Ring Issue 480](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/issues/408#issuecomment-633264110); turns out this may be a design bug looking for a contributor.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a server which will serve `index.html` if present inside a `resources/public/` folder.

```clj
(ns core
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [routes GET]]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults]]
            [org.httpkit.server :as http-kit]))

(def handler
  (routes
    (GET "/foo" [] "Hello Foo")
    (GET "/bar" [] "Hello Bar")))

(def app
  (-> handler
   (wrap-defaults {:static {:resources "public"
                            :files     "resources/public"}})))


(def server (http-kit/run-server app {:port 8889}))

(comment
  ;; To stop the server
  (server))
```

I'm using `wrap-defaults` as it provides a nice way to get a server up and running, while still providing a lot of flexibility to drop in customisations as required.

In this case I'm telling it to use `public` as a resources folder and also handing it `resources/public` to files so it can correctly wrap the files to be served.

`ring.middleware.content-type` defaults to `application/octet-stream` when it has insufficient information to guess the content type of the file it is serving.

If you specifically just want to serve files+provide routing, the answer I have given above is sufficient, if you want to explicitly return a `Content-Type` `text/html` for `index.html`, then you will need to wrap the content type using `[ring.util.response :refer [content-type]]`.

So for example:

```clj
(GET "/" [] (content-type (io/resource "index.html") "text/html"))
```

I've normally done this by detecting the file extension in the request url and then returning the correct `content-type`, with a special case for things like `index.html`.

You need at least these deps, this is in `deps.edn` format, but just change it to `[ring/ring-core "1.8.0"]` for example if you need it in lein's `project.clj` form instead:

```clj
ring/ring-core                    {:mvn/version "1.8.0"}
ring/ring-defaults                {:mvn/version "0.3.2"}
http-kit                          {:mvn/version "2.3.0"}
compojure                         {:mvn/version "1.6.1"}
```

Let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Much appreciated, but I don't think it answered my question, as my goal actually isn't to get a server up. I'm successfully serving index.html in all cases, actually. It's that the Content-Type: text/html appears when I specify index.html specifically in the URL, but gives me Content-Type: application/octet-stream if I use just the base URL. I'm curious what I can do with that Middleware specifically, as it's part of a larger chain. But I do appreciate the example for study purposes, nonetheless. Thank you.

Comment: I've added some additional detail that does hopefully cover your question specifically, unfortunately I don't have time to do more than sketch out the code required. Sorry I can't help more at the moment =)...

Comment: Again, I want to thank you for pointing me at wrap-defaults; my experiments showed that your code behavedg identically to the behavior I was seeing (that is, it would deliver the correct root index document, but at the same time give it the wrong content-type). It appears that your current workaround is identical to my work around -- however, just like mine, it doesn't scale -- subdirectories have the same problem. Much appreciated for your time, the dialogue was useful. Not looking for you (or others) to write my code for me, just trying to grok the middleware quirks to fix the issue.